# Converting between a number to a string without num2str

Tags: string, matlab, converters

For example, input is a=`5678`. How do you make b=`'5678'`? (b is a String).
Not allowed to use str2num or any casting.

Is it possible to use `log10`? (I know how to do the reverse action).
[This is how I did the opposite (from string to num):

`s = input('Enter a number: ','s');
x = sum(10.^(length(s-'0')-1:-1:0).*(s-'0'));`

Comment: I suggest `mod` rather than `log10`

Comment: ... but you're right, `log10` may also be needed. Is this homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like homework, so first here are some hints:

- `log10` may be useful to determine the number of digits.
- `mod` can help to obtain each digit.
- From your code for the reverse action: using successive powers of `10`, as well as `+'0'` / `-'0'` to convert between digits and ASCII codes, may also be of help here.

And here's a possible approach using these hints (hover the mouse to find out):

> `b = char(mod(floor(a./10.^((ceil(log10(a))-1):-1:0)),10) + '0'):`

Comment: haha wow + 1 for the 'hover-the mouse' effect that's nice! How can you do that?

Comment: @Benoit_11 :-) Just add `>!` in front of each line you want to "hide". You can find that in the "advanced help" when writing your answer.

Comment: Great I'll definitely use this sometime! :)

Comment: WOAH! HIDING CODE!  COOL!

Comment: Uh oh, @rayryeng has discovered the spoiler tag. ;)